Error when accessing Amazon RDS via JawsDB
I recently deployed my website using Netlify for front-end and Heroku back-end, with JawsDB to handle my MySQL database. I'm able to make GET requests to my server and receive data from my db, and information from the database renders on the front-end as intended, so I know I'm accessing the database correctly.
However, I have a route for authentication, when I try to access it, I get a 500 error with this response:
{message:"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND jaxxxxxxxxxwe.qexxxxxxsf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"}

What might be causing this, and how can I resolve it?
I ran heroku logs --tail and got this when trying to authenticate:
[2024-10-17T02:06:59.520160+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND jaxxxxxxxxxwe.qexxxxxxsf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306

2024-10-17T02:06:59.520162+00:00 app[web.1]: at PromisePool.query (/app/server/node_modules/express-mysql-session/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:356:22)

2024-10-17T02:06:59.520163+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/server/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:384:30

2024-10-17T02:06:59.520163+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)

2024-10-17T02:06:59.520163+00:00 app[web.1]: at MySQLStore.query (/app/server/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:381:10)

2024-10-17T02:06:59.520164+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/server/node_modules/express-mysql-session/index.js:232:16

2024-10-17T02:06:59.520164+00:00 app[web.1]: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

